# JavaScript is not working in text template in backbone.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

I want to apply bootstrap datepicker library for date input. I am using backbone and I have templates. I've writing the following code:

```
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#date').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev) {
             $('#date').val = new Date(ev.date);
         });
     });
 </script>
```

I have included the datepicker library as well. I want to apply this on template:

```
<script type="text/template>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="startDate">Start Date</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="input-xlarge datepicker" id="startDate"  value="02/16/12" />
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

But, this code is not working. If I apply my html code outside template then it will work, but in the template it is not working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View.render() is returning the view's HTML and is not yet rendered on the DOM. Therefore, you should put your template inside the render function and initialize your plugin after you call render(). I haven't test it but done this many times ... :)..so, this is just to give you idea...

```
var yourView = Backbone.view.extend({
   my_template: "#your-template",
....

render: function() {
   _.template(my_template, my_data);
}
...

});

yourView.render();

$('#date').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    $('#date').val = new Date(ev.date);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code

```
var yourView = Backbone.view.extend({
   my_template: "#your-template",
....

render: function() {
   _.template(my_template, my_data);
setTimeout(function() {
        $('#date').datepicker()
    },0);
}
...

});

yourView.render();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `datepicker` function and bind the handler after you render the template, or else the element isn't in the DOM to apply the datepicker to.

E.g., it would look something like this in your View's `render` function:

```
_.template(my_template, my_data);
$('#date').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    $('#date').val = new Date(ev.date);
});
```

Also, your selector in the JavaScript is for an ID of `date` but your template's input has an ID of `startDate`. They'll both need to match.

Comment: my render function is now look like this:                         this.$el.append( _.template(CampaignTemplate));
  $('#startDate').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev) {
  $('#startDate').val = new Date(ev.date);
      console.log($('#startDate').val())  ;
  });
  this._modelBinder.bind(this.model, this.el);               Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker' backbone.js:1081 @freejosh

Comment: Are you sure you're including the plugin properly? Sounds like it's not loaded into jQuery.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `this.$('#date')` in case the view's `el` hasn't been added to the DOM yet?

Comment: @muistooshort Yea, probably. I just meant my code to be an example of placement. My `_.template` result doesn't even get assigned anywhere.